# Microsoft Bot Framework Dialog Chain, retry previous dialog based on condition

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I'm currently using the Microsoft Bot Framework to create a Facebook Messenger chatbot. I'm using the [dialog chaining syntax](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/de/dab/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_chain.html#af1213116d6b46a88b675b691bb357d7a) to ask a user for an address and to get them to confirm this, mainly using ContinueWith to get the result from the previous dialog and use that in the next.

At one point however I want to show a PromptConfirm Dialog which shows the user the address they have added and asks them if this is correct with a yes or no response. If the user clicks no I want to take them back to the previous dialog to ask them again and not let them continue. How do I do this?

I've tried various keywords like Where (just continues anyway) and Loop (loops the whole chain back to the start) with no luck. Any pointers would be welcome.

**Update:** The most helpful article I've found so far is [this one](https://dgkanatsios.com/2016/10/31/developing-a-bot-for-parkaround-using-microsoft-bot-framework/) that has a LoopWhile statement with a condition. Unfortunately though it again loops the whole chain up to that point whereas I just want to go back to the previous dialog in the chain.

Comment: Any reason you are using Chain? Have you considered using standard dialogs?

Comment: @EzequielJadib got it working with standard dialogs before but writing a chain seemed a much more succinct way of doing it and easier to read IMO.

Comment: Chain could become really complex to read as soon as you start adding more scenarios.

Comment: @EzequielJadib I guess you're right there. Happen to know any good samples of more complicated bots? All the examples I've found are very simplistic

Comment: In https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp you will find a lot of samples. The ContosoFlowers sample specifically has many moving pieces.